# Python: Saving all instances from inside a loop to variable to call later

Tags: python, variables, csv, pandas, iteration

I'm working with Pandas and a CSV file that I'm iterating through in order to find every occurrence of a specific color and then returning the image's name. 
For example, I have a dataframe:

```
    imageName   color1   color2   color3   color4  
    1           Blue     Blue     Blue     Blue 
    2           Pink     Magenta  Red      Purple
    3           Blue     Blue     Blue     Blue
    4           Blue     Yellow   Teal     Teal
    5           Yellow   Blue     Red      Purple
    ...
```

What I'm doing is printing the image name each time a specific color is mentioned.

```
   for index, row in df.iterrows():
      if (row['color1'] == 'Blue' and row['color2'] == 'Blue' and row['color3'] == 'Blue' and row['color4'] == 'Blue'):
         allBlue = (row['imageName'])
```

This gets me the results that I want, but if I call my variable allBlue from a different file, it just returns the last instance since it's not in a for loop. Is there a way to save the whole print out to a variable to call later from a different file?

Like this: When I call it from inside loop

```
Occurrences of all Blue Shapes:
1
3
6
19
...
178
```

Instead of this: When I call it from other file

```
Occurrences of all Blue Shapes:
178
```

I'm fairly certain I'm just forgetting something obvious or not thinking about something clearly, but any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: use a list `allBlue = []` and append to the list `allBlue.append(row['imageName'])` then iterate over the list `for iter in allBlue`. Is that something you would want to do ?

Comment: I tried this, but I'm getting a "[]" as the resulting list. I put allBlue = [] outside my loop, the 'for iter in allBlue' the original for loop and my if statement, then appended it in my if statement. Is this the wrong order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the loop to find images-with-a-color in pandas. However, I put in a loop that uses the accumulator-list in the right place as an example (`colorcols`):

```
import pandas as pd

cdf = pd.DataFrame({'color1': {0: 'Red', 1: 'Blue', 2: 'Yellow', 3: 'Blue'},
 'color2': {0: 'Red', 1: 'Green', 2: 'Blue', 3: 'Blue'},
 'color3': {0: 'Red', 1: 'Red', 2: 'Red', 3: 'Blue'},
 'color4': {0: 'Red', 1: 'Blue', 2: 'White', 3: 'Blue'},
 'form': {0: 'circle', 1: 'circle', 2: ' square', 3: 'circle'},
 'imageName': {0: 'img1', 1: 'img2', 2: 'img3', 3: 'img4'}})

colorcols = []
for i in range(1,5):
    colorcols.append('color%d'%i)

for color in set(cdf[colorcols].values.flatten()):
    mask = (cdf==color)
    print('%s: '%color),
    colors = (mask.sum(axis=1) > 0)

    print(cdf[colors].imageName.values)
```

> ```
> Blue:  ['img2' 'img3' 'img4']
> White:  ['img3']
> Green:  ['img2']
> Yellow:  ['img3']
> Red:  ['img1' 'img2' 'img3']
> ```